# What would be the time complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, big-o

```
class AllSubMatrices {

    int a[][] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }, { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 },
            { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 } };

    AllSubMatrices() {
    }

    int printSum(int r, int c, int len) {

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = r; i < (r + len); i++) {
            for (int j = c; j < (c + len); j++) {
                sum = sum + a[i][j];
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public void allSubMatrices() {
        for (int l = 1; l <= a[0].length; l++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (a[0].length - l); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= (a.length - l); j++) {
                    System.out.println(printSum(i, j, l));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the time complexity of allSubMatrices? The book I am refering to (Cracking the coding interview) mentions o(n^4). But that is not convincing to me since the all the loops do not run for N times, it is variable from 1 to N. I feel itshould be o(n^2).

Comment: How many numbers does it print?

Comment: What is the value of n? Width = Height = n ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's even *O*(*n*^5). I have no exact proof, but an illustration. If you count only the steps of the loops you get:

```
sum(1 <= l <= n){sum(1 <= i <= n - l){sum(1 <= j <= n - l){ j^2 }}}
```

The three sums describe a triangular figure which arises through a cube cut (tetraeder). The volume of this figure grows like *O*(*n*^3) with the sum of squares the complete formula grows like *O*(*n*^5).

Answer (score 0):

If n = width = height here, then it can't be O(n^2) because if we take all external loops in allSubmatrices only, they will be O(n^3) already. The two inner loops in printSum are more interesting, they are basically l^2 operations, where l is the variable of the very outer loop that counts from 1 to n. If we count only one outer loop plus the printSum call, the number of operations will be a sum of all squares of n numbers which is n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6, i.e O(n^3). If we add two more loops, it will be O(n^5).

Answer (score 0):

`printSum(_, _, len)` does `len^2` additions to `sum`

Then, assuming the width and height of the array are the same, and calling the width/height of the array `n`, the overall complexity is:

```
sum(sum(sum(l^2 for j=0..n-l) for i=0..n-l) for l=1..n).
= sum((n-l+1)^2 * l^2 for l=1..n).
```

Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum((n-l%2B1)%5E2%20*%20l%5E2%20for%20l%3D1..n).) to simplify gives:

```
1/30 * n * (n + 1) * (n^3 + 4n^2 + 6n + 4)
```

That's O(n^5).

Incidentally, the code in the question has a problem. It looks like it's written to support non-square matrices (and indeed, the example matrix is 4x5). But the code does not function correctly if the width is smaller than the height, since `l` ranges only 1 to `a[0].length`. Correct would be to range between 1 and `max(a[0].length, a.length)`. If you're representing the contents of the book correctly, that's two errors in the same problem.